# ASP.NET MVC with OpenIDConnect authentication fails with multiple instances of the service running

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

We have MVC Web Application with AnjularJS integrated (legacy product) and deployed as a Web Application. We expose ApiControllers for Ajax calls from the AngularJS script .We have multiple instances of this application running behind a load balancer. We recently integrated Azure AD for authentication and use OpenIDConnect flow. User login succeeds but subsequent requests (Ajax calls) to the ApiControllers fail randomly with 'Unauthorized' error.

**OpenIDCOnnect Authentication setup**

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);       
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = "XXXXX",
        Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = @"https://localhost:44360/",
    });
}
```

Then each MVC and API controller is annotated with Authorize attribute

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
```

**Our Analysis**

We suspect this issue might be because of the application running multiple instances and during login the session would be established with that particular instance. Subsequent requests are going to other instances randomly and the instance does not have the session information. When we deploy only one instance of the application, this error is not seen.

**Questions**

1. When I read online about Azure AD, the recommended way for Ajax calls is to use ADAL.js implicit flow. Since ours is not a purely single page application, I am not sure if this would be a valid choice. We want to see if we can solve this by sticking to OpenIDConnect.
2. Is there a way to store this session information in a distributed store so that multiple instances of the application can share it? I see interface ***IAuthenticationSessionStore*** in ***CookieAuthenticationOptions*** which can be used but not finding enough information on its purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a JS app using the MVC app to service API/AJAX requests then the MVC app should not use cookies at all. It should just validate the id_token passed from the JS client in the Authorization header. Your app is failing probably because you are trying to use cookies, encrypting them on one server and then trying to use them on another. Have a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v1-code#single-page-applications, particularly the source code for the Startup.Auth.cs class: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp/blob/master/TodoSPA/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs.

If you are mixing SPA (JS) paradigm with serving regular HTML then you have will have to figure out how to use both cookies and tokens. Tricky and insecure.